# Samba Performance between Ubuntu 23.10 and Windows 11 is slower than I believe it should be at about currently between 30 to 50+ Megs Per Second

Tags: samba

Everytime I goto transfer files between Ubuntu 23.10 and Windows 11 Pro 23H2 it seems to be quite a bit slower than normal speeds at about between 30 and 50 or so Megs Per Second..  I am copying on the Ubuntu 23.10 from the Windows 11 Pro 23H2 computer and right now it is working just slower than I believe it should be in this case!!  So, Any ideas here how to fix or workaround the problem possibly??

Comment: How are you mounting the Win11 share? Through Nautilus or through mount.cifs?

Comment: via Nautilus and Samba...

Comment: What's your connection? That is, how do you "transfer files between Ubuntu 23.10 and Windows 11 Pro"?

Comment: Via Wired Lan Connection at 1Gigs Per Second LAN Network Connection... I am using onboard LAN Chipset on both ends as well...

Comment: Consider setting up a HTTP server on the transmitting end and a browser on the receiving end for faster speeds.

Answer (score 0):

> How are you mounting the Win11 share? Through Nautilus or through
> mount.cifs? – Morbius1 ...
>
> via Nautilus and Samba... – Joel Craycroft001

There are two ways to mount an smb share in Ubuntu:

[1] via Nautilus which mounts under /run/user/$UID/gvfs/

*There's a lot of overhead using this method: nautilus itself, the gvfs backend, the smb client library which it calls, etc ....*

[2] A CIFS mount - as in mount.cifs.

*Controlled by the Linux kernel directly.*

You may see no difference in speed between the two methods but I suggest you do a temporary mount using cifs and see if it improves:

Create a mount point for the Win11 share - example:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Win11share
```

Then mount it - temporarily:

If you allow guest access:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //win11-host-name.local/win11-share-name /media/Win11share -o guest,uid=1000
```

If you require credentials:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //win11-host-name.local/win11-share-name /media/Win11share -o username=xxxx,password=yyyy,uid=1000
```

Replace win11-host-name win11-share-name xxxx, and yyyy with their appropriate values.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about connect to the Win11 and it's share like you always do and post the output of this command:

```
ls -l /run/user/$UID/gvfs
```